# How to get a different hexadecimal value from the previous value generations?

Tags: python, loops, random, hex

```
import os,binascii
print binascii.b2a_hex(os.urandom(1))
```

I am creating a hexadecimal value using `os.urandom` as you can see above, I need to generate 15 *different* values.

I got as far as generating the values, but I don't know how to make it so that all the values are different from the values generated before. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the easiest solution is to generate a list of all the values, [shuffle](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.shuffle) it and then just iterate over them like this:

```
import binascii
import random

byte_list = [i for i in range(256)]
random.shuffle(byte_list)
for byte in byte_list:
    print binascii.b2a_hex(chr(byte))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to guarantee uniqueness, you could keep populating a `set` until it's the correct length. Sets don't allow duplicate values. If you need it as a list you can easily convert it with `list()`.

```
def get_random(n):
    out = set()
    while len(out) < n:
        out.add(binascii.b2a_hex(os.urandom(1)))
    return list(out)

print get_random(15)
```

Of course for this one, you need to be careful there are enough random values to fill an `n` length list otherwise you'll end up caught in an endless loop.